getting prisma types into jsdoc and shown in docdash
im trying to build some api docs with jsdoc and docdash. im importing types from prisma into my jsdox types and thats working fine.
what i cant get to work:
getting the prisma types to show up, expanded, in docdash.
how im attempting to bring in a prisma type and create a jsdoc type/namespace so it will show up in docdash
/** @namespace Document */

/**
 * @import { Document } from '@prisma/client'

 * @typedef {Document} Document
 */

and this is what im getting in docdash
docdash docs
what im hoping for:
im hoping to display a full prisma type in docdash. ideally i would be able to import it from prisma and expand it somehow to be visable and clickable in docdash
